# blazor - EditorRequired attribute

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

```
 @code {
     [Parameter, EditorRequired] 
     public Trail Trail { get; set; } = default!;
 }
```

What does this mean

1. `EditorRequired`
2. `public Trail Trail { get; set; } = default!;` (why default and why exclamatory mark?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What does this mean
>
> 1. EditorRequired

It is a hint to the user of your component that `Trail` is a required parameter. When you  'forget' Trail, as in `<MyComponent />` you will get a warning, and some squiggly lines under that usage.
The warning in your Build output is

`RZ2012 Component 'MyComponent' expects a value for the parameter 'Trail', but a value may not have been provided.`

> 2. public Trail Trail { get; set; } = default!;
>    (why default and why exclamatory mark?)

This is a way to reduce warnings. When you omit `= default!;` you will get the  warning:

`CS8618 Non-nullable property 'Trail' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor.`

Together these two features provide a reasonable way to work with nullable reference types in Blazor. It is not air-tight, you can still get null-reference exceptions. But not as easily anymore.

What you have here is a standard pattern and a best-practice.